# Unable to hit POST service in Angular 6 TS

Tags: angular, typescript, web-services, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I'm unable to call the post service in my TS. I'm getting data from the user in a form and am saving this data into an array and showing this data in a table. After that I click another button to save my data and which calls a service which is not working and not showing any error. I also call two other services on this button click it's working fine but my array service not working.

Service.ts

```
insertAddresses(formData: SettingsAddressesModel) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/SettingAddress/SaveAddress", formData);
  }
```

Component.ts

```
insertAddressList(compIDforAddress){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.childSettingAddressComponent.SettingsAddressesList.length; i++){
      this.childSettingAddressComponent.SettingsAddressesList[i].ElementID = compIDforAddress;
      //this.addressService.insertAddresses(this.childSettingAddressComponent.SettingsAddressesList[i]);
      console.log('address data', this.childSettingAddressComponent.SettingsAddressesList[i]);
    }
    this.addressService.insertAddressListArray(this.childSettingAddressComponent.SettingsAddressesList);
    console.log('Address Elment ID:', compIDforAddress);
  }
```

Comment: please check for CORS is enabled

Comment: where is your subscribe method?

Comment: @HameedSyed that's right !  you need  to subscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe for any call that is asynchronous.Otherwise they will not execute.

Modify your code in `component.ts` like below :

```
  this.addressService.insertAddressListArray(this.childSettingAddressComponent.SettingsAddressesList)
.subscribe((result)=>{

    // result will contain the response from service  
     console.log('Address Elment ID:', compIDforAddress); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe and also log the errors if any since post method silently fails in most case if not handled properly.

```
this.addressService.insertAddressListArray(this.childSettingAddressComponent.SettingsAddressesList)
.subscribe((result)=>{    
    // result will contain the response from service  
     console.log('Address Elment ID:', compIDforAddress); 
    },
     (error)=>{
     console.log("error "+error);
     }
);
```